# Is there any way to build RESTful web service and exposing to consumer as SOAP?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I want to create a RESTful web service. But the consumer wants to consume it as a SOAP service and wants to send SOAP requests. Is there any way I can wrap my RESTful web service so that it can accept and return the SOAP format?

(The reason I want to do this is to support other existing services in the system which are RESTful.)

Comment: What are your assets?  What platform are you working on / language / tools?  Knowing this might produce a better answer.

Comment: Are you using .NET? Java? PHP? COBOL?

Comment: *Why* does the client want SOAP? Is it their favorite buzzword? Or do they have a legitimate reason (i.e. they need to interface with existing SOAP-speaking software)?

Comment: Just create a SOAP Facade over your existing webservice and translate the message between the two layers in your facade

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details, you could create a SOAP web service that simply calls your Rest Service by implementing a web service client on your platform of choice.  If the backend logic should remain unchanged and you essentially want an interface of a different flavor, this would be a feasible way to implement what you are thinking of.

**Edit**

If you have your class files in hand, you could look at using AXIS2 to generate the SOAP Client for you.  It would be pretty straight forward to put a REST interface in front of the generated client classes.

Check the documentation for an example of generating a SOAP client: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients-xmlbeans.html